# Does 5e have any kind of permanent injury rules?

Tags: dnd-5e, injury

In my last game, an unfortunate circumstance befell my character:

I was engaged with two ghosts, however, the "master" of the ghosts (who had been appearing and disappearing at random) had just reappeared in the middle of the room. He had taken a bit of a beating already, so I decided I would do my best to finish him off.

I managed to get in range to use my breath weapon (I am a Dragonborn), but, since I had been previously engaged, the two ghosts got opportunity attacks as I left their range.

2 natural d20s.

Needless to say, the damage dealt was more than my hit points could handle, so the DM struck a deal: he would let me make my attack, if I gave something to him in return. We eventually settled on a permanent injury, when my character regained consciousness.

So I looked around, did a bit of researching, and I'm not sure, but there doesn't appear to be any kind of injury system in 5e. Is that the case?

Comment: Honestly, if you're not sure what the rules are that apply to an unusual situation, the answer is *always* to ask your GM. Not only does this guarantee you'll get the rules that are relevant, you'll also get any houserules that might apply, as well as the easy opportunity to ask follow-up questions if anything is unclear.

Comment: Lingering injury rules can take all the fun out of a character. Having something nasty that you know is going to be penalising your character for many levels to come... that can suck. Think carefully about whether you'll enjoy this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Optional rules for *Lingering Injuries* can be found on page 272 of the DMG and be used at the DM's discretion.

Healing can remove the injury as written, but a DM could always rule otherwise.

Comment: Those rules are optional at DM discretion, right?

Comment: Yes any rules variant in the DMG are not in the vanilla version of the game.